# jquery - Linking an appended element to its parent:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Maybe it's just late, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around this.

I have a delete link that, when clicked, is replaced in the same spot with OK/Cancel links: the one fades out, the other fades in. The whole construct looks like this:

```
<div class="selfConfirm" data-props='{"idproduct": 1, "idcategory": 2}' >
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    <div style="display:none;">
        <a href="#" class="ok">OK</a> / <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The links and click events are built at runtime using jquery. Building the links works fine, and I can attach a click event to the delete link and the OK and cancel links.

There could be a dozen or more such constructs on the page and what I'd like is for each one - and whatever parent container each happens to be in - to act like a unit. Click a delete link and the appropriate OK/cancel fades in, and they each get what they're acting on from the parent (in this example, removing a product from a category. )

I guess my question is: how would I link them together, so that when I click a "delete" link I don't get EVERY OK/Cancel on the page fading in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [jQuery closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) where you can pass a selector. So it starts at the given point where you `click` on the element with `$(this)` and goes up the DOM tree until it finds the first selector passed in the function...

```js
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next('.hidden-buttons').toggle();
});

$('.cancel').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.hidden-buttons').hide();
});


$('.ok').on('click', function() {
    console.log(
      $(this).closest('.selfConfirm').data('props')
    );
    console.log(
      'idproduct: ' + $(this).closest('.selfConfirm').data('props').idproduct
    );
    console.log(
      'idcategory: ' + $(this).closest('.selfConfirm').data('props').idcategory
    );

});
```

```css
.hidden-buttons {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selfConfirm" data-props='{"idproduct": 1, "idcategory": 2}' >
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    <div class="hidden-buttons">
        <a href="#" class="ok">OK</a> / <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="selfConfirm" data-props='{"idproduct": 2, "idcategory": 2}' >
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    <div class="hidden-buttons">
        <a href="#" class="ok">OK</a> / <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="selfConfirm" data-props='{"idproduct": 3, "idcategory": 2}' >
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    <div class="hidden-buttons">
        <a href="#" class="ok">OK</a> / <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the ok cancel div block using the [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function in jQuery like this:

```js
$(".delete").click(function() {
   $(this).hide().siblings(".okCancelBtns").fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-props='{"idproduct": 1, "idcategory": 2}' >
    <a href="#" class="delete selfConfirm">Delete</a>
    <div style="display:none;" class="okCancelBtns">
        <a href="#" class="ok">OK</a> / <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-props='{"idproduct": 1, "idcategory": 2}' >
    <a href="#" class="delete selfConfirm">Delete</a>
    <div style="display:none;" class="okCancelBtns">
        <a href="#" class="ok">OK</a> / <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-props='{"idproduct": 1, "idcategory": 2}' >
    <a href="#" class="delete selfConfirm">Delete</a>
    <div style="display:none;" class="okCancelBtns">
        <a href="#" class="ok">OK</a> / <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I thinking for using `.after()` .*I don't know why I think like that* but I felt its very simple thing to just write `<a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>` and then on click the code will append the buttons next to this button. so your code should be something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.delete').on('click' , function(){
    $('.ok-cancel').remove();
    $(this).after('<div class="ok-cancel">'+
                  '<a href="#" class="ok">OK</a> / <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>'+
                  '</div>');
  });
  
  $(document).on('click' , '.ok' , function(){
    alert('OK');
  });
  $(document).on('click' , '.cancel' , function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selfConfirm" data-props='{"idproduct": 1, "idcategory": 2}' >
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
</div>

<div class="selfConfirm" data-props='{"idproduct": 1, "idcategory": 2}' >
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
</div>


<div class="selfConfirm" data-props='{"idproduct": 1, "idcategory": 2}' >
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
</div>
```